# Get the index of combination by its value

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The formula below gives a total number of combinations of K values, each no greater than M, and whose sum is exactly N (zeros and different orderings are accounted, that is 1 + 4 and 4 + 1 are different combinations). Clearly, each combination can be deterministically assigned with an index within this known volume of all possible combinations. **The problem:** for the known combination, would it be possible to reconstruct back its index? The order of enumeration does not matter.

[image: The total number of combinations]

The procedure in question is also referred to as *unranking* and *place of a combination in the ordering*. According to a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system), the index can be revealed by accounting all k-combinations preceding the one of an interest. The difference of my case above is that combinations are order-sensitive. So the original question yields to doing a proper modification of this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple ranking algorithm with respect to the lexicographic ordering. Let $s$ be a sequence whose first entry is $i$, and where the deleting the initial $i$ leaves the sequences $s'$ of length $k-1$. Then all of the sequences coming before $s$ lexicographically fall in one of two categories:

- Sequences starting with $j$ where $j<i$.
- Sequences starting with $i$, such that the substring $t$ left when you delete the initial $i$ occurs lexicographically before $s'$ (among sequences of length $k-1$ summing to $n-i$).

Letting $f(n,k,m)$ be the number of sequences of length $k$ with sum $m$ and maximum allowed entry $m$, it follows that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(s)=\operatorname{rank}(s')+\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}f(n-j,k-1,m)
$$

Here is an example; letting $n=8,k=4$, and $m=5$, find the rank of  $(3,1,0,4)$ among all sequences with length $4$, sum $8$, and max entry $5$. We start with
$$
\def\r{\operatorname{rank}}\r(3,1,0,4)=\r(1,0,4)+\sum_{j=0}^2 f(8-j,4-1,5)
$$
You know how to compute the $f$'s, so you know how to compute the summation. All that remains is to compute $\r(1,04)$, which we do in the same way:
$$
\r(1,0,4)=\r(0,4)+\sum_{j=0}^0 f(5-j,3-1,5)=\r(0,4)+f(5,2,5)
$$
Note that the $n,k,m$ in the $f$ formula are computed from the current sequence, $(1,0,4)$, not the initial sequence $(3,1,0,4)$. In this case, the sum had a single term, the $j=0$ term. Next,
$$
\r(0,4)=\r(4)+\sum_{j=0}^{-1} f(4-j,2-1,5)=\r(4)
$$
In this case, there is nothing to sum over, since there are no numbers $j$ for which $0\le j\le -1$. The empty sum is just zero.

Finally, $\r(4)=1$, since there is only one entry of length $k=1$ with sum $n=4$. This is always the base case; the rank of a single entry sequence is $1$ (or zero, if you are zero-indexing).

Comment: Thanks, could you please help me to understand this formula by a concrete example. For instance, combinations(n = 4, k = 8, m = 4) gives 330 combinations in total.  Let our combination of interest be (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1). The f is the combinations counter that I use, right? And I re-apply it for the ranges of n and k, then sum them. But how do I know the rank(s') ?

Comment: You just compute rank(s') with a recursive call to rank.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an instructive example! I've drafted a program for it in C++: https://gist.github.com/dmikushin/046a8007021e24dfbc393873f39f9f4c Returns 106. But for (3, 1, 0, 5) it also returns 106, which is confusing. Maybe the algorithm needs to amend a special action on the last remaining entry?

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem is that you are treating $n$ and $k$ as constant. These need to be recomputed from the current list when you recurse on that list. For $(3,1,0,4)$, you initially have $n=8$ and $k=4$, but when you recurse to $(1,0,4)$, instead $n=5$ and $k=3$. Your mistake may have been caused by a typo in my answer (now fixed), in which case I apologize.

Comment: @DmitryMikushin Here's my python solution if it helps: https://replit.com/@mearnest/Ranking-die-rolls#main.py

Comment: Also, there is not theoretical problem with $(3,1,0,4)$ and $(3,1,0,5)$ having the same rank, since they are not being ranked in the same list (first has $n=8$, second has $n=9$).

Comment: Fantastic, it works! I've corrected my bugs in the C++ code in the Gist above. Enlarged m, n, k to 16, 8, 10, and it works as well. Truly amazing work, perfect math!

Comment: Now I want to look how to eliminate the recursion in the ranking. I believe it's possible to turn it into a plain loop, which is better for computing.

Comment: @DmitryMikushin You can definitely do it iteratively! Do a small example by hand, writing out all of the $f(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ values being added together, and it should be clear how to loop over them all.