# Get the sum-constrained combination sequence by its lexicographical index

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

I need to solve the inverse of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186930/get-the-index-of-combination-by-its-value). Suppose we are given the rank `49510`, meaning we want to find the `49510`-th lexicographically ordered combination in a sequence of length `8`, maximum allowed element value of 10 and elements sum of `16`. The expected result is `{ 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0 }`.

There is a code already implementing the opposite (see below). The task of getting the sequence from rank appears to be more challenging. On the positive side, there is only one rank for each sequence, and the sum of elements is known. On the hard side, I guess I need to factorize the sum into binomial coefficients. How should I proceed about this?

```
template<
    uint32_t n, // sequence elements sum
    uint32_t k, // length of sequence
    uint32_t m  // max allowed sequence element value
>
static uint32_t rank(const uint32_t* sequence)
{
    // Evaluate, each time omitting the leading term of sequence.
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0, sum = n; i < k - 1; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < sequence[i]; j++)
            result += popcount(sum - j, k - i - 1, m);

        sum -= sequence[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

or, in more detail:

```
template<
    uint32_t n, // sequence elements sum
    uint32_t k, // length of sequence
    uint32_t m  // max allowed sequence element value
>
static uint32_t rank(const uint32_t* sequence)
{
    // Evaluate, each time omitting the leading term of sequence.
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0, sum = n; i < k - 1; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < sequence[i]; j++)
        {
            auto nn = sum - j;
            auto kk = k - i - 1;
            int m1 = -1;
            uint32_t sum = 0;
            for (int ii = 0, e = nn / (m + 1); ii <= e; ii++)
            {
                m1 *= -1;
                result += m1 * choose(kk, ii) * choose(nn - ii * (m + 1) + kk - 1, kk - 1);
            }
        }

        sum -= sequence[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by "backing out" of the algorithm given in the linked post, although there is almost certainly a more efficient way to do it. The general idea is:

- Given $S(k, m, n)$ as the number of ways to make the sum of $n$ from $k$ values from $\{0, \ldots, m\}$, calculate $a_j = S(k - 1, m, n - j)$ for $j \in \{0, \ldots, m\}$, and then find the largest value of $J$ for which $\sum_{j = 0}^J a_j$ is still below the index.
- Set that value of $J$ as the next digit, then go back to the previous step but replacing $k \rightarrow k - 1$ and $n \rightarrow n - J$.
- Repeat until $k = 0$.

I say this is incredibly inefficient because the recursion will end up calculating a lot of similar terms. A dynamic programming approach which is able to save and quickly reference the calculations from other loops will almost certainly wind up being better, but that's not something I have much experience in.

Comment: Perfect, it works, thanks a lot! I've only noticed the algorithm expects 1-based index

Comment: How do I modify this algo for a sequence of combinations with elements sum less or equal than n?

Comment: Never mind. I've figured it out.