# Get mixed sum-constrained and unconstrained combination sequence by its index

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

This is a harder variation of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495051/get-the-sum-constrained-combination-sequence-by-its-lexicographical-index/4495062#4495062). We are given a combination formed by sum-constrained and unconstrained parts:

- n - sum-constrained sequence elements sum,
- k1 - length of sum-constrained sequence,
- m1 - max allowed sum-constrained sequence element value,
- k2 - length of unconstrained sequence,
- m2 - max allowed unconstrained sequence element value.

Unconstrained part comes after constrained, for example:

$n$ = 16, $k1$ = 8, $m1$ = 10, $k2$ = 2, $m2$ = 3:

- combination = `{0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1}` has the rank of `120993` (unconstrained part is the last {0, 1} pair),
- combination = `{0, 0, 4, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2}` has the rank of `220994` (unconstrained part is {0, 2}).

**The goal is** to develop an algorithm that can recover a combination according to the parameters, and the given rank value. So, for example given `420995`, we must answer `{0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 3}`.

Although the solution is trivial for constrained and unconstrained parts alone, I don't know how to proceed about decomposing the rank into constrained and unconstrained parts. What am I missing?

Comment: Replied to your email, but got an error message back saying that it was unable to deliver it to your email address. I'm afraid that I don't know much about sum constrained sequences. But, there is a "trivial solution" of iterating from zero. That will work for small sequences and would be useful for testing purposes. I think you need to scour the Internet for theorems, formulas, and the like for a more efficient solution.

Comment: @BobBryan thanks, I have the solution for constrained sequences already (it's mentioned in the referenced post). The problem is really about "mixing" two sub-sequences of different types in one sequence.